# How to create LEFT JOIN with SELECT subquery using QueryBuilder in Doctrine 2?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, left-join

I need to limit LEFT JOIN results, so I must use subquery.
Could somebody give me advice how can I do it with Doctrine 2?

What I have now is:

```
  $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    return $qb->add('select', 'c,j')
             ->add('from', 'JobeetBundle:Category c')
             ->leftJoin('c.jobs', 'j', 'WITH', 'j.category = c')
             ->add('where', 'j.expiresAt > ?1')
             ->add('orderBy','j.expiresAt DESC')
             ->setParameter(1, new \DateTime())
             ->getQuery()
             ->getResult();
```

but I must change it to limit jobs results to 10 by every category.

Comment: How to build subquery in Doctrine2 you can [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637506/doing-a-where-in-subquery-in-doctrine-2#6638146).

Comment: Thanks but probably I can't pass sub select to join in QueryBuilder, I need to use native SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, This is not possible.  Per here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/0rNbXlD0E_8

You can do it using IN here:

[Doing a WHERE .. IN subquery in Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637506/doing-a-where-in-subquery-in-doctrine-2#6638146)