# Doctrine2 from subqueries

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I need to convert the following code to doctrine but cant seem to find the right Doctrine2 function.

```
Select 
ProductName,
WeekNumber,
sum(sale)
from
(
    SELECT 
    ProductName,
    DATEDIFF(week, '2011-05-30', date) AS WeekNumber,
    sale
    FROM table
)
GROUP BY
ProductName,
WeekNumber
```

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637506/doing-a-where-in-subquery-in-doctrine-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine 2 ORM does not support subqueries in the `FROM` clause. The only allowed locations for a subquery are the `WHERE` and the `HAVING` clauses, which are supported by the various RDBMS vendors.

Please check the complete [EBNF](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#ebnf) of DQL