# DQL INNER JOIN with Zend Framework 2 / Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, dql

With this SQL-Statement, i can fetch the latest messages from all users:

```
SELECT  m1.*
FROM    message AS m1
INNER JOIN user
   AS u1
   ON m1.sender_id = u1.user_id
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT   sender_id,
   MAX(dateSent) MaxDate
   FROM     message
   WHERE receiver_id = 4
   GROUP BY sender_id
) AS m2
ON m1.sender_id = m2.sender_id
AND m1.datesent = m2.MaxDate;
```

**Those are my Entities in my Zend Framework 2 application:**

First, i got the Message. A User can send a Message to another user.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="message")
 */
class Message
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entities\User", inversedBy="messagesSent")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="user_id")
 */
private $sender;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entities\User", inversedBy="messagesReceived")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="user_id")
 */
private $receiver;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1024)
 */
private $message;
```

And the User entity here:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $user_id;
```

I **tried** to translate that **SQL into DQL** and got this:

```
SELECT  m1.*
FROM    Application\Entities\Message AS m1
INNER JOIN Application\Entities\User AS u1
    WITH m1.sender_id = u1.user_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  sender_id,
    MAX(dateSent) MaxDate
    FROM    Application\Entities\Message
    WHERE receiver_id = 4
    GROUP BY sender_id
) AS m2
WITH m1.sender_id = m2.sender_id
AND m1.datesent = m2.MaxDate;
```

If i execute it, i get an error from Doctrine:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 206 near '(
      ': Error: Class '(' is not defined.
```

What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries are unavailable in doctrine(as far as I know) in DQL(from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637506/doing-a-where-in-subquery-in-doctrine-2#6638146)). Can you write it [query builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods)?

```
public function innerJoin($join, $alias = null, $conditionType = null, $condition = null);
```

See [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637506/doing-a-where-in-subquery-in-doctrine-2#6638146)