# Doctrine2 join doesn't works with delete

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Repository class I've created method `applyCriteria()`:

```
protected function applyCriteria(QueryBuilder $qb, array $criteria)
{
    $qb->leftJoin('co.file', 'file');

    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('file.someField', $criteria['someField']));

    return $qb;
}
```

I use it in two methods:

```
public function findByCriteria(array $criteria = [])
{
    $qb = $this->applyCriteria($this->createQueryBuilder('co'), $criteria);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}

public function deleteByCriteria(array $criteria = [])
{
    $qb = $this->applyCriteria($this->createQueryBuilder('co'), $criteria);

    $qb
        ->delete()
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute()
    ;
}
```

So, `findByCriteria()` works fine, but calling `deleteByCriteria()` throws Doctrine Exception with message `Error: 'file' is not defined.` What may cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out. If anybody will need the same: [Doctrine QueryBuilder delete with joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301636/doctrine-querybuilder-delete-with-joins)

The problem is that DQL really do not works with joins in delete queries. So we should use EntityManager and remove entities one-by-one or create another spikes.