# Delete many to many relationship with DQL

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity Article with a collection of tags (many to many relationship) in my SF2 project.

```
class Article
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Namespace\Entity\Tag", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $tags;
```

In my business logic, this article can contain lots of tags. 
In my application, the user can reset all theses tags in one shot. So I have to delete all my references in the join table.

To reduce my number of doctrine queries, I would like to do that with DQL (to be consistent) but I can't find a way.

Comment: Please take a look in here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301636/doctrine-querybuilder-delete-with-joins Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Create `removeTags($article)` method in your custom [EntityRepository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) and put something like:

```
DELETE FROM article_tag WHERE article_id = :article
```

I can't test it right now, but this should work.

Comment: Thanks but this is an SQL query, not DQL.