# Doctrine cascade update - reset child entity before persist on update

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, innodb

I have a `Promotion` Entity having a One-to-Many relationship with `PromotionCategory` Entities.

In the `Promotion` Entity I have:

```
/**
 * @var PromotionCategory[]
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="AwinServices\Modules\AdvertiserPromotion\DomainLayer\Models\Promotion\Category", mappedBy="promotion", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
public $promotionCategories;
```

And in the `PromotionCategory` Entity I have:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="AwinServices\Modules\AdvertiserPromotion\DomainLayer\Models\Promotion", inversedBy="promotionCategories")
 * @JoinColumn(name="promotionId", referencedColumnName="promotionId")
 **/
public $promotion;
```

The problem I am having is that every time I update a Promotion with a new Category, it keeps on creating new PromotionCategory entities for that Promotion.

What I want is to reset the previous categories for that Promotion, and create new rows for the categories I am passing.

To solve the issue currently I am trying to remove all the Categories for that promotion before persisting using a DQL DELETE statement:

```
$q = $this->doctrineEntityManager->createQuery("Delete from " . $this->getEntityClassname() . " r where r.promotion =" . $promotion->id);
$q->execute();
```

I assumed Doctrine will do that automatically as it does for ManyToMany relationships and don't understand why it doesn't do this for my case even after mentioning `cascade={"persist", "remove"}`

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Shouldn't you have a Many to One relationship from Promotion -> Promotion Category? I obviously don't really know what you're trying to accomplish in your code but it seems odd that a single promotion would belong to more than one category.

Comment: Also, if you're using Symfony in debug mode you should be able to see the mysql queries that doctrine is running when you execute `$q->execute()`;

Comment: Decave, my system dictates that a Promotion can have multiple category, hence One to Many. $q->execute() I am doing is something that I don't want to do. I want to update the Promotion Category table with new set of Ids when Promotion get updated, just like doctrine does it for Many to Many tables.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `cascade={"persist", "remove"}` only applies if you persist or remove the `Promotion` *parent* of the `PromotionCategory` object. What you're trying to do is remove the `PromotionCategory` children of a Promotion object, so the `cascade` keyword is irrelevant in this case.

That being said, the problem with your query is that you're not joining on the Promotion entity in your query. Doctrine apparently has trouble doing this in `DELETE` statements, as can be seen in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301636/doctrine-querybuilder-delete-with-joins).

As @Danielle Suurlant says in that post, one way to do this is to fetch the `PromotionCategory` entities you want to remove from the database, and then just remove them with the entity manager:

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select('AwinServices\Modules\AdvertiserPromotion\DomainLayer\Models\Promotion\Category', 'category')
  ->innerJoin('category.promotion', 'promotion')
  ->where('promotion.id = :promotion_id')
  ->setParameter('promotion_id', $promotion->id)
  ->getQuery();
$results = $query->execute();
```

Then iterate over the results and remove them:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $this->entityManager->remove($result);
}
```

And flush to get rid of them:

```
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Thanks again to Danielle Suurlant for her answer to this similar problem in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301636/doctrine-querybuilder-delete-with-joins).

Comment: Thanks, Decave for you time. That is exactly what I am doing currently but in a more Domain Driven fashion.