# Delete with join - Alias not defined

Tags: symfony, dql, symfony-3.4

Upon making a change in my database, I'm to delete some related entries in another table.

I made a custom query in my Repository:

```
public function removeOptionGc(VarianteEscalier $varianteEscalier) {
    $em=$this->getEntityManager();

    return $em->createQueryBuilder()
              ->delete(VarianteEscalierOptGc::class, "vogc")
              ->join("vogc.gardecorpsOption", "gco")
              ->where("vogc.varianteEscalier=:VARIANTE")
              ->andWhere("gco.type='option_gc_rampant' OR gco.type='option_gc_etage' OR gco.type='autres'")
              ->setParameters(array('VARIANTE'=>$varianteEscalier))
              ->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
}
```

When I execute it, I will get the following error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 94 near 'gco.type='option_gc_rampant'': Error: 'gco' is not defined.

This is the DQL I get from this query:

```
DELETE AppBundle\Entity\VarianteEscalierOptGc vogc WHERE vogc.varianteEscalier=:VARIANTE AND (gco.type='option_gc_rampant' OR gco.type='option_gc_etage' OR gco.type='autres')
```

Any idea as to why `join` is ignored when I try a `delete`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine QueryBuilder delete with joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301636/doctrine-querybuilder-delete-with-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of the developer of Doctrine itself, the answer is that many vendors do not support `JOIN` in `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements, and Doctrine does not include features that are not cross-platforms (almost verbatim what he said).

See full discussion: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2716