# Nested select query in doctrine query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql, doctrine-query

In a Symfony2 project:

```
select * from
(
    select
        p.name as product, u.id, u.name
    from user u
    left join product_purchase pp on pp.user_id = u.id
    left join product p on pp.product_id = pp.product_id
    where p.type = 'something'
    order by p.id desc
) as up
group by up.id;
```

This is simplified query I want build with Doctrine Query Builder but couldn't find a solution yet. The important thing is ordering on join before grouping the result. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `up.id` in your example supposed to be? Is it `u.id` from the subquery? Can you give an example of how the data in your database look like and what result you would like to get returned?

Answer (score 2):

this is a example may help you because vote and check good response. He use a second queryBuilder var in a first qb with `$qb->expr()->in(` : [subquery in queryBuilder Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637506/doing-a-where-in-subquery-in-doctrine-2)

Comment: thanks for pointing out the answer; I had tried using second querybuilder in `->from` but it didn't work out