# Nested query in Doctrine query builder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How to build nested query with Doctrine Query Builder?

My mysql query looks like this:

```
SELECT subquery1.*
FROM 
 (SELECT * FROM product 
  WHERE for_her = true && age_teenagers = true && special = true) subquery1
WHERE subquery1.song_rock =true || subquery1.describe_beauty = true;
```

How to convert this into Doctrine query in Product Entity Repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the query might be easily reformated to usual not-nested query.
As far as I see it's

```
SELECT * FROM product 
  WHERE for_her = true AND age_teenagers = true AND special = true
and (song_rock =true OR describe_beauty = true)
```

And therefore

```
Select P from Product P
Where P.forHer=true AND P.ageTeenages=true AND P.specials=true and (P.songRock=true OR P.describeBeauty=true)
```

Comment: By all records, that is not true! Check the SO q/a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637506/doing-a-where-in-subquery-in-doctrine-2