# Search for Entity that has multiple tags in doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a many to many relation between Document and Tag. So a `Document` can have several `Tags`'s, and one `Tag` can be assigned to different `Document`'s.

This is `Tag`

```
AppBundle\Entity\Tag:
    type: entity
    table: tags
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\TagRepository
    manyToMany:
        documents:
          targetEntity: Document
          mappedBy: tags
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        label:
            type: string
            length: 255
            unique: true
```

And `Document`

```
AppBundle\Entity\Document:
type: entity
table: documents
repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\DocumentRepository

manyToMany:
    tags:
      targetEntity: Tag
      inversedBy: documents
      joinTable:
          name: documents_tags
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    title:
        type: string
        length: 255
```

Now I want to search for all Documents that has the tags `animal` and `fiction`. How can I achieve that with doctrine?

Something like

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Document');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('d');
$query  ->join('d.tags', 't')
                ->where($query->expr()->orX(
                            $query->expr()->eq('t.label', ':tag'),
                            $query->expr()->eq('t.label', ':tag2')
                        ))
                ->setParameter('tag', $tag) 
                ->setParameter('tag2', $tag2)
```

wont do the job, because it returns all Documents that have either `tag1` or `tag2`. But `andX` won't work too, because there is no single tag that has both labels.

Comment: I think you will need to make a subquery, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637506/doing-a-where-in-subquery-in-doctrine-2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this with additional inner joins for each tag:

Example:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Document');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('d');
$query->innerJoin('d.tags', 't1', Join::WITH, 't1.label = :tag1');
$query->innerJoin('d.tags', 't2', Join::WITH, 't2.label = :tag2');

$dql = $query->getDql();
$result = $em->createQuery($dql)
    ->setParameter('tag1', 'LabelForTag1')
    ->setParameter('tag2', 'LabelForTag2')
    ->getResult();
```

Maybe this little image helps understanding what this query does. The whole circle represent all your documents. If you are only using one single join, the query will return either the green+red or the blue+red part.
Using an additional inner join, you will only get the intersection of the joins seen individually (which is only the red part).

[image]

If you have even more tags to search for, you can simply add another join for that.

Comment: looks like it works, and pretty good explanation, thanks bountyhunter, get your bounty :)

Comment: im really not even interrested in this question or answer,   but wanted to say props for adding this image !

Comment: This is a good solution while your database is not so big and the number of tags for the query is low. For big databases or complex queries I'm using Elasticsearch. It may sound like an overkill, but as the site grows is worthy to consider this approach.