# Doctrine return error with "eq", no with "in"

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

With Symfony and Doctrine, I have an error with "eq" subquery :

**It's OK, no error :**

```
public function getForums()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('fc');

    return $qb
        ->innerJoin('fc.versions', 'fcv')
        ->innerJoin('fc.versions', 'fcvl', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->in(
            'fcvl.id',
            $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('MAX(v.id)')
                ->from(ForumCategoryVersion::class, 'v')
                ->where('v.forumCategory = fc')
                ->getDQL()
        ))
        ->select('fc, fcv')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

**Replace `in` by `eq` :**

```
public function getForums()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('fc');

    return $qb
        ->innerJoin('fc.versions', 'fcv')
        ->innerJoin('fc.versions', 'fcvl', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->eq(
            'fcvl.id',
            $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('MAX(v.id)')
                ->from(ForumCategoryVersion::class, 'v')
                ->where('v.forumCategory = fc')
                ->getDQL()
        ))
        ->select('fc, fcv')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

I have this error :

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 208: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'

Comment: Use `in` then, instead of `eq`. What is your question?

Comment: Actually, on a 2nd thought, you could create an enhancement issue on doctrine `s github repo and ask to make the use of parenthesis optional. It is weird to be supported on one case and not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **parenthesis**  **()** for the **subquery**:

```
->innerJoin('fc.versions', 'fcvl', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->eq(
        'fcvl.id',
        '(' . $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('MAX(v.id)')
            ->from(ForumCategoryVersion::class, 'v')
            ->where('v.forumCategory = fc')
            ->getDQL() . ')'
    ))
```

References

- [Mysql equal subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparisons-using-subqueries.html)
- [Doing a where in with doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637506/doing-a-where-in-subquery-in-doctrine-2)