# How to make an Where In subquery in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I'm trying to do this SQL query with Doctrine QueryBuilder:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE NOT id in (SELECT event_id FROM ues WHERE user_id = $userID)
```

The UserEventStatus has foreign keys from User and event, as well as an integer for status.
I now want to query all events that dont have an entry in UserEventStatus from an particular User.
My function for this in the EventRepository looks like this:

```
    public function getUnReactedEvents(int $userID){
        $expr = $this->getEntityManager()->getExpressionBuilder();
        $originalQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');
        $subquery= $this->createQueryBuilder('b');
        $originalQuery->where(
            $expr->not(
                $expr->in(
                    'e.id',
                    $subquery
                        ->select('ues.user')
                        ->from('App/Entity/UserEventStatus', "ues")
                        ->where(
                            $expr->eq('ues.user', $userID)
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        return $originalQuery->getQuery()->getResult();

    }
```

But i get an error that says: 
`Error: Method Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager could not be converted to string (500 Internal Server Error)`
Can anyone help me or point me to right point in the docs? Cause i failed to find something that describes my problem. 
And another thing is, that I don't know if its possible, but it would be nice. Can I somehow make direct Object requests? I mean not with the string `App/Entity/UserEventStatus` but with something like UserEventStatus::class or something.
Thanks for your help in advance. :)

EDIT: It has to be `$originalQuery->getQuery()->getResult()` of course.
If its like it was with $subquery instead i recive `[Semantical Error] line I0, col 41 near 'App/Entity/UserEventStatus': Error: Class 'App' is not defined. (500 Internal Server Error)`

Second EDIT:

```
        $expr = $this->getEntityManager()->getExpressionBuilder();
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

        $subquery= $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->select('ues.user')
            ->from('UserEventStatus', "ues")
            ->add('where', $expr->eq('ues.user', $userID));

        $originalQueryExpression = $expr->not($expr->in('e.id', $subquery));

        $queryBuilder->add('where', $originalQueryExpression);

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Third EDIT: Thanks to @Dilek I made it work with a JOIN. This is the final Query:

```
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->leftJoin('App\Entity\UserEventStatus', 'ues', 'WITH', 'ues.user=:userID')
            ->setParameter('userID', $userID)
            ->where($expr->orX($expr->not(
                $expr->eq('e.id','ues.event')
            ),
                $expr->not($expr->eq('ues.user', $userID)))
            );


        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building AND WHERE into a Query

```
public function search($term)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('cat')
        ->andWhere('cat.name = :searchTerm')
        ->setParameter('searchTerm', $term)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
```

simple is: `->where('cat.name = :searchTerm')`

**UPDATE :**

I think you need to use where in

```
$qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('ues.user', $userID));
```

[And WHERE Or WHERE](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/and-where-or-where#building-and-where-into-a-query)

Comment: changing it to andWhere didnt help much... can't I put an expression into where?

Comment: See updated answer $qb is $originalQuery and there is a sample with simple where clause in answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Unfortunately I still recive the same Error.... with the toString method...

Comment: I put it like it is now in an new edit in the origonal post, maybee i did oversee something :)

Comment: @CKWDani stop updating your question please, and  Try Like this `->where($qb->expr()->in('ues.user', $userID))`  set paramaeters if needed `->setParameter();` qb is `db` instans

Comment: ues is actually another table, so it now throws ```Error: 'ues' is not defined```. I addaed it to the main queryBuilder, so the subquery is not used anymore, so I think it does not know which ues I am talking about when Ad it instead of the ```in expression```. If I ad it instead of the ```eq``` expression I still remain with the same error (_toString)

Comment: are you using left join ? that error means ues table not found, see this answer as an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57322563/where-in-query-with-sub-query-in-doctrine-querybuilder-or-equivalent

Comment: Thanks for that Idea. Didnt think about it yet :)

Comment: @CKWDani See here might help **how to create subqueries** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762586/how-to-convert-this-to-doctrine-2-querybuilder-format/10763358#10763358

Comment: @CKWDani glad I helped, I didnt its a query from two tables at the beginig)