# join on subquery in Sonata Admin/ Symfony doctrin-orm query-builder

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4, query-builder, sonata-admin, sonata

When I try joining the subquery in the following function of a Sonata Admin Panel Class

```
protected function configureQuery(ProxyQueryInterface $query): ProxyQueryInterface
```

I always get the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 44 near 'JOIN (SELECT': Error: Subquery is not supported here
```

First i create my subquery:

```
 $sub = $qb->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

 $sub->select(array('c', 'count(c.user)'))
        ->from('App\Entity\UserComment', 'c')
        ->groupBy('c.user');
```

Then I try to join it (I also tried to join with $sub->getQuery->getSQL() but same error):

```
 $qb->leftJoin(sprintf('(%s)', $sub->getDQL()), 'counter', Join::WITH, 
 $sub->getRootAliases()[0].'.user = counter.user')
      ->setParameter('isReported', true);
```

In my opinion this would give back valid dql:

```
SELECT o FROM App\Entity\UserComment o LEFT JOIN (SELECT c, count(c.user) FROM App\Entity\UserComment c GROUP BY c.user) counter WITH c.user = counter.user
```

Is there a workaround for this problem?
The exact description of what I want to do is the following stackoverflow question: 
[Symfony Sonata Admin Panel order by occurrence count (doctrin query builder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62103760/symfony-sonata-admin-panel-order-by-occurrence-count-doctrin-query-builder)